# Reading dictionaries in other forms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Novice VB user here. Hope I haven't been staring the answer in the eye for the past day or so but I have a made a dictionary in `Form1` that I would like to read onto a listbox on another form entirely with the hopes of being able to add and remove the entries with buttons. What is the best method to go about this? Have really come stuck here.

Using Visual Basic 2015 with Windows Form Application.

Thanks in advance!

This is the mentioned dictionary I would like to read on a listbox on the other form.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim userLog As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    userLog("one") = "aaa"
    userLog("two") = "aaa"
    userLog("three") = "aaa"

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this Web Forms? Or Windows Forms? You should always be clear what the framework you're using is by tagging your question appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. Will update accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to display an editable Dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798933/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-display-an-editable-dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

Create a public property instead of a private variable

```
Public Property userLog As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

You can access it from other forms using `Form1.userLog`

Read more in this [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

To solve the problem consider these facts:

- ListBox is not a good choice for creating or editing a `Dictionary`. `DataGridView` is much better.
- To pass an object to another form, it's enough to add a suitable parameter to the constructor of other form and pass data to constructor.

[image: Dictionary in Grid]

**Dictionary Edit Form**

In this example, I've created a form to edit a dictionary. Please pay attention to this points:

- I created a `DataTable` from dictionary and then set the `DatTable` as `DataSource` of `DataGridView` and at last put items back to the dictionary.
- I set `Key` column as `PrimaryKey` of `DataTable` to make key unique.
- I Handled `DataError` event to show error if you enter an invalid key
- To put back items to dictionary, I first tried to add items to an empty dictionary and at last if the task is successful, I cleared the main dictionary and put items back into dictionary.

Here is the source code of the example:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class DictionaryEditForm
    Public Sub New(ByVal Dictionary As Dictionary(Of String, String))
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.Dictionary = Dictionary
    End Sub
    Public Property Dictionary() As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim Table As DataTable
    Const Key As String = "Key"
    Const Value As String = "Value"
    Private Sub DictionaryEditForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Table = New DataTable()
        Table.Columns.Add(Key, GetType(String))
        Table.Columns.Add(Value, GetType(String))
        Table.PrimaryKey = {Table.Columns(Key)}
        For Each item In Dictionary
            Table.Rows.Add(item.Key, item.Value)
        Next
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Table
    End Sub
    Private Sub SaveButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click
        Dim temp As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        For Each item As DataRow In Table.Rows
            temp.Add(item.Field(Of String)(Key), item.Field(Of String)(Value))
        Next
        Dictionary.Clear()
        For Each item In temp
            Dictionary.Add(item.Key, item.Value)
        Next
        Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_DataError(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DataError
        MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message)
        e.Cancel = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Usage**

It's enough to create an instance of `DictionaryEditForm` and pass the dictionary to its constructor, then you can edit the dictionary usnig it.

```
Public Class MainForm
    Private Sub EditDictionaryButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles EditDictionaryButton.Click
        Dim Dictionary = New Dictionary(Of String, String) From
            {{"1", "One"}, {"2", "Two"}, {"3", "Three"}}
        Dim f = New DictionaryEditForm(Dictionary)
        f.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Class
```